# Change the foreground color of read-only properties in a propertygrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I'm using a WinForms property grid to display the properties of an object. However, most of the properties are read only and thus show up as grey rather then black. Is there a way to customize the colors that are used? I'd like the disabled properties to be a bit easier to read.

BTW: I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136129/windows-forms-how-do-you-change-the-font-color-for-a-disabled-label) might be related to what I'm trying to do. But I'm not sure exactly how I can access `ControlPaint.DrawStringDisabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to change the colour. As with a lot of the standard .NET controls, they're merely wrapped versions of their COM equivalents.

What this means in practice is that a lot, if not all of the painting is done by the COM component, so if you try overriding the .NET `OnPaint` method and calling `ControlPaint.DrawStringDisabled` or any other painting code, it's more than likely going to have an undesired effect, or no effect what-so-ever.

Your options are:

1. Build a custom control from scratch (probably the easiest)
2. Override `WndProc` and try to intercept paint messages (not guaranteed to work)
3. Attempt to override `OnPaint` and do your painting on top (not guaranteed to work)

Sorry that's probably not the answer you wanted, but I can't think of an easier method. I know from bitter experience that this sort of thing can be hard to modify.

Comment: While it doesn't change anything on the outcome, the explanation in this answer is wrong, PropertyGrid is neither a wrapper nor based on COM, its implementation is fully in .NET

Answer (score 13):

This problem has a simple solution.

Just reduce R in the RGB for forcolor of the PropertyGrid, like this:

```
Me.PropertyGrid2.ViewForeColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 0)
```

This feature just acts on black color.

Comment: How the hell does this work? It is hackish, but gave the desired result. When will this fail and how?

Answer (score 0):

What sorcery is this? +1! I have seen other solutions that trap mouse and keyboard. This is by far the best and easiest solution. Here is a snippet of my inherited read-only control.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MyCustomControls
{
    public sealed class ReadOnlyPropertyGrid : System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid
    {
        #region Non-greyed read only support
        public ReadOnlyPropertyGrid()
        {
            this.ViewForeColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 0);
        }
        //---
        private bool _readOnly;
        public bool ReadOnly
        {
            get { return _readOnly; }
            set
            {
                _readOnly = value;
                this.SetObjectAsReadOnly(this.SelectedObject, _readOnly);
            }
        }
        //---
        protected override void OnSelectedObjectsChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetObjectAsReadOnly(this.SelectedObject, this._readOnly);
            base.OnSelectedObjectsChanged(e);
        }
        //---
        private void SetObjectAsReadOnly(object selectedObject, bool isReadOnly)
        {
            if (this.SelectedObject != null)
            {
                TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.SelectedObject, new Attribute[] { new ReadOnlyAttribute(_readOnly) });
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
        //---
        #endregion
    }
}
```