# Formating the content/properties of a Winform PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

(1) Is it possible to format/change the font/color of a particular porperty name in a Winform propertygrid?

In the following example on property name ("Cursor") is red:

[image]

(2) Is it possible to change the order of categories or are they fixed alphabetical? in my case I want to have one particular category on top.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the foreground color of read-only properties in a propertygrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420252/change-the-foreground-color-of-read-only-properties-in-a-propertygrid)

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to do here? Various things are possible using attributes like `DisplayName`, custom type-converters, custom property-descriptors, custom type-description-providers, custom UI-type-editors, etc - all very complex, though: so what *exactly* do you want to change?

Comment: You cannot change the key (left column) appearance, only the value (right column) appearance. The only thing you can change about the key appearance is a read only property which makes its font gray, but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set `Font` for the propertygrid, try this:

```
propertyGrid1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 20f);
```

Also you can set `PropertySort` for it which will mimic its original behavior (like the one in the VS). Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.propertysort.aspx)