# How to change forecolor of disable checkbox in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, groupbox

I am working in windows application that has a form.this form contains a group box that has some check-boxes. I have set this group box as disable. Now my problem is the fore-color of check-box text.It becomes light gray as shown in picture below.

[image]

How can I change the fore color of check box's text so it do not look like disabled(Light gray).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002615/text-color-of-disabled-control-how-to-change-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002615/text-color-of-disabled-control-how-to-change-it)

Comment: You've to paint manually

Comment: This question for label, but I think you can get a idea by reading this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136129/windows-forms-how-do-you-change-the-font-color-for-a-disabled-label

Comment: You're fighting against the very behavior you've asked for.  The controls in the `GroupBox` belong to it, and therefore abide by its _disabled_ state.  If you don't want that, don't put them in a group.

Answer (score 14):

Don't disable it, just put AutoCheck property = False

Comment: But in case I want to disable the whole panel that contains the CheckBox, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have *owner-drawn* `CheckBox` already (or is it a component of someone), so solution with painting its text in needed color, disregards `Enabled` value, is the right one.

Other possibility would be do not disable parent container of `CheckBox`'es, then there are a lot of possibilities:

- Do not disable `GroupBox` (this is made for a reason, users are used to use that);

  - Prevent `CheckBox`'es from being *clicked* somehow (though this is not in requirements): by setting `AutoCheck` to false, by reverting `Checked` value back in `OnCheckedChanged`;
- Do not host controls inside disabled `GroupBox` (smells hacky ^^):

  - Use *floating* panel, `GroupBox` is under and not a parent;
- Do not use `GroupBox`
- Use custom `GroupBox`

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I used on forms with dark BackColor and light ForeColor.  The ForeColor on Labels, CheckBoxes and GroupBoxes turn black when they're disabled, so instead of using doing Form1.Enabled=False or Panel1.Enabled=False or GroupBox1.Enabled=False, I use Form1.Controls.SetEnabled(False), Panel1.SetEnabled(False) or GroupBox1.SetEnabled(False).  For the extension to work, you'll need to add "Imports Extensions" in the class you wish to make the extension available.

```
Public Module Extensions
        ''' <summary>Sets Enabled property on most controls, set AutoCheck property on CheckBox controls, and ignores GroupBox and Label controls if Enabled parameter equals False.</summary>
        ''' <remarks>Purpose: Disabled GroupBox, Label, and CheckBox controls have Black ForeColor when disabled, making it difficult or impossible to read if background is dark color.</remarks>
        ''' <example>Instead of Panel1.Enabled=False, use Panel1.Controls.SetEnabled(Enabled:=False)</example>
        <Extension()>
        Public Sub SetEnabled(ByRef Controls As System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection, ByVal Enabled As Boolean, Optional ByVal Recursive As Boolean = True)
            For Each c As Control In Controls
                If Enabled = False Then
                    ' Do not disable some controls such as group boxes
                    Select Case c.GetType
                        Case GetType(GroupBox), GetType(Label)
                            ' Do nothing to control
                        Case GetType(CheckBox)
                            ' Change AutoCheck property instead
                            DirectCast(c, CheckBox).AutoCheck = False
                        Case Else
                            ' Disable control
                            c.Enabled = False
                    End Select
                Else
                    Select Case c.GetType
                        Case GetType(CheckBox)
                            ' Set Enabled and AutoCheck properties to true for CheckBox controls
                            With DirectCast(c, CheckBox)
                                .AutoCheck = True
                                .Enabled = True
                            End With
                        Case Else
                            ' Enable all other Controls
                            c.Enabled = True
                    End Select
                End If

                If Recursive = True AndAlso c.Controls IsNot Nothing AndAlso c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                    c.Controls.SetEnabled(Enabled, Recursive)
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
End Module
```